# How are notches calculated for boxplots that represent non-parametric data?

Tags: variance, standard-error, median, boxplot

I was interested in finding the theory behind the formula used to calculate where notches are to be placed in a boxplot to signify 95% confidence interval, which is median +/- 1.57*IQR/sqrt(n). [An earlier answer related to the '1.57' multiplier goes into explaining that 1.57 was chosen empirically.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/184516/why-is-the-95-ci-for-the-median-supposed-to-be-%C2%B11-57iqr-sqrtn) I have also read elsewhere that this is valid only for normally-distributed data. So I was wondering how might the formula change if I have sets of non-parametric data? Thanks!